# How to use connectOrCreate with many to many in prisma

Tags: database, blogs, prisma

I want to use Prisma to associate articles with tags, that is: A post has multiple tags and a tag belongs to multiple posts
But the example in Prisma will result in the creation of duplicate tags

Here is my Prisma model

```
model Article {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  title     String
  summary   String
  link      String   @unique
  archive   String
  content   String
  image     String
  tags      Tag[]
}

model Tag {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  articles Article[]
}
```

This is my code according to the documentation, it causes duplicate tags to appear

```js
await prisma.article.create({
  data: {
    title,
    summary,
    link,
    archive,
    content,
    image,
    tags: {
      create: tags.map((tag) => ({ name: tag })),
    },
  },
});
```

When I use connectOrCreate, it reports an error in many-to-many mode

```js
await prisma.article.create({
  data: {
    title,
    summary,
    link,
    archive,
    content,
    image,
    tags: {
      connectOrCreate: {
        where: tags.map((tag) => ({ name: tag })),
        create: tags.map((tag) => ({ name: tag })), 
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: what's the reason to use `tags.map((tag) => ({ name: tag }))`  within your code ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's two errors in the code.

#### `Tag.name` field is not unique

From what I can infer from your domain, two tags should not have the same name. Furthermore, since the `name` field is not unique, you can't use it by itself to uniquely identify a specific `Tag` record and so Prisma will complain if you try to pass only the `name` field in the `where` condition of `connectOrCreate`.

The simplest and logical solution to this is to make the `name` field unique. Here's your updated Tag model

```
model Tag {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String    @unique  // change
  articles Article[]
}
```

#### Incorrect syntax for `connectOrCreate`

You're passing separate arrays to the `where` and `create` fields. Instead, when you want to connect/create multiple records, pass an array of objects to `connectOrCreate` each with its own `where` and `create` field. Here's an example from the Prisma Docs that shows [how to use connectOrCreate with multiple records](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create-a-deeply-nested-tree-of-records).

This is what your create query should look like:

```js
await prisma.article.create({
  data: {
    title,
    summary,
    link,
    archive,
    content,
    image,
    tags: {
        connectOrCreate: tags.map((tag) => {
            return {
                where: { name: tag },
                create: { name: tag },
            };
        }),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver. I just want to add, since it might not be obvious by the wording, that  the bullet points the author has mentioned work in tandem. It's not either or but utilizing both at the same time. This solved my issue. Thank you!